# Problem trying to upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04.1 to 20.10

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 20.10

Hello I am having issues trying to upgrade to 20.10 from 20.04.1 LTS.
The upgrade process stops and it goes back to the original state. Here it is the error I got:

```
Error in function: install

apt_pkg. Error: E:Unable to configure "libc6:amd64". , E:Configuration could not be performed immediately on "libnss-nis:amd64". For more information, see "man 5 apt.conf" in the "APT::Immediate-Configure" section (2).
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f) method
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
apt_pkg. Error: E:Unable to configure "libc6:amd64". , E:Configuration could not be performed immediately on "libnss-nis:amd64". For more information, see "man 5 apt.conf" in the "APT::Immediate-Configure" section (2).
Error in function: install

apt_pkg. Error: E:Setup could not be performed immediately on "libffi8ubuntu1:amd64". For more information, see "man 5 apt.conf" in the "APT::Immediate-Configure" section (2).
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f) method
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
apt_pkg. Error: E:Setup could not be performed immediately on "libffi8ubuntu1:amd64". For more information, see "man 5 apt.conf" in the "APT::Immediate-Configure" section (2).

Unable to install version feeds 

The progress has stopped: the system may be in a 
been unusable. a restore will start (dpkg --configure 
-a). 

Impassable progress 

Progress has not been completed: errors have occurred 
during processing. 

Restoring the original state of the system
```

I have no idea why that does happen.

EDIT: translation in english

Comment: Best if you could repost this in English.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/FMCsc96sZ4/) is the results I got from running it through a translator. I don't know how accurate it is, so I'm reluctant to edit the post with that data.

Comment: Looks like the translation is correct, I forgot to translate it